# How to find which thread is stuck

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I'm working with threads and one (or more) of my thread(s) is/are stuck and never ends. The problem is that I can't find which one.

So I'd like to know if there is a way to find it's `ID`, the same ID that is shown in `PS` Linux command. If there isn't a way, how could I find which thread is stuck ??

Obs: Already checked the `pthread_self()` and it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: `ps` is not listing threads without a special switch. Are you sure you want threads and not processes?

Comment: Please see the following information: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @EugeneSh. I guess so... When I compile with the character `&` am able to give the `PS` command, and I can see my executable there listed with an pid. I just wondered if there is a way to find which thread is stuck...

Comment: `pid` = `process id`. Not thread. You better describe your problem in detail. Not the problem arising from something you think to be a solution to the original problem. See -[XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using GDB debugger we can find out which thread is in blocking state.

1. First try to compile your code with debug symbols.
2. `gdb your_file_executable`
3. put some break point ( you would be knowing where to place the bp exactly )
4. `info threads`

" info threads " will give information about the threads which is spawned/running . w

Comment: Another command I found useful is `thread apply all bt` - it prints a stack trace of every thread, allowing you to somewhat easily find the stuck one.

Comment: Can also do: gdb program -p pid